# Styles not being applied while using .modules.scss in Next.js

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, sass, next.js13

I've started a Next.js 13 app,

I have a `main.modules.scss` file

```
.heading {
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: #000;
}

.dark .heading {
    color: #fff;
}
```

I am using it to style a component like this

```
import styles from "@/styles/main.module.scss";

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <h1 className={styles["heading"]}>Hi! I was styled by scss</h1>
        </>
    );
}
```

The styles from the `.heading` class are getting applied properly, but the properties from .dark .heading are not.

My theme provider does add a `.dark` class to the HTML element.

I used a plain .scss file and applied a class something like this

```
    <h1 className="heading">Hi! I was styled by scss</h1>
```

Then it worked perfectly fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:global` to state that you are using a global class

so your `main.modules.scss` will become

```css
.heading {
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: #000;
}

:global(.dark) .heading {
    color: #fff;
}
```

### Why does this work?

> Warning: I am not a CSS expert

CSS modules are scoped to component they are used in.

This mean by default the `.dark` selector gets transpiled and does not refer  to the global `.dark` class.

- Check out [this post](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/) for a more info about CSS modules
- Check [this blog post](https://www.thecodeforge.io/post/how-to-use-the-parent-selector-in-css-modules) for more info about the use of `:global`

Comment: thanks, that worked,
:global(.dark) is not too much extra code,
could you please explain why it won't work without the global state

Comment: I updated the post to include more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `styles.heading`.

```
<h1 className={styles.heading}>Hi! i was styled by scss</h1>
```

Comment: thanks but as had mentioned,
the .heading part was working fine,
.dark .heading was not,

which means that styles["heading"] was doing it's job as expected